# When ViewModel class need to create in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, module, viewmodel

I have followed Magento_Catalog Module and I have found

**ViewModel folder there.**

Can anyone please explain when we need to create ViewModel classes when we creating our custom module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ViewModel is a replacement of Block in Magento 2.

When we create any Block file and we need certain data in the template, we define a function in that Block file.

In most cases, we need some custom classes to be injected in the Block constructor to get the data and pass it to the template.

Now to do that, we have to forcefully add 2 additional parameters `$context` and `$data`, which we do not need it in our template.

So the ViewModel is a concept to make us follow the **SOLID principle (One class, One responsibility)**.

Overall, you can use ViewModel to avoid defining additional constructor argument `$context` and `$data`, and code only what you actually need.

According to the documentation, Block will only be needed if you want to set template file name dynamically or change something in Block functions like **_prepareLayout**, apart from that, if your template file is fixed, and you want to get data from some collection or model, you can use ViewModel.

You can define ViewModel in layout XML like the following way.

```
<block name="myblock" template="MyCompany_MyModule::template.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">MyCompany\MyModule\ViewModel\MyClass</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Here, it will take Magento's default block as Class which we normally use to extend our block.

You can create ViewModel file something like below.

> MyCompany/MyModule/ViewModel/MyClass.php

```
<?php

namespace MyCompany\MyModule\ViewModel;

class MyClass implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        SomeCollection $collection
    ) {
        $this->collection = $collection;
    }

    public function getItems($subscription)
    {
        $collection = $this->collection->create();
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

So this way, we code what we actually need.

In your phtml template file, you can call ViewModel function as below.

```
$collection = $block->getViewModel()->getItems();
```

I hope it gives you clarity on ViewModel.