# When use block vs view model?

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, viewmodel

I'm creating a module using blocks and view models, but when is it better to use [view models](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html) instead of blocks?

Comment: See this answer. It might be helpful for you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277947/when-viewmodel-class-need-to-create-in-magento2/277954#277954

Answer (score 1):

> You just need a Block if you want to set a template filename dynamically or change something in Block functions like **_prepareLayout**, apart from that, if your template file is fixed, and you want to get data from some collection or model, you can use ViewModel.

These are two great references about it:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/277954/16416

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html